# LC-3: JSR does not modify PC

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm working on a program in LC-3 assembly, and I am having an issue with `JSR`. Instead of modifying the PC, jumping to the label, and writing the previous PC to R7, it merely continues to the next instruction. Here is the relevant section:

```
....
NXTNODE     LDR     R2, R2, #0  ; get next node
BRz DONE    ; now that node is loaded in R2, compare the first and last name

AND R6, R6, #0
AND R3, R3, #0
AND R3, R4, #0  ; copy search term pointer to R3
ADD R6, R2, #0  ; copy node pointer to R6
ADD R6, R6, #3  ; point to last name
AND R5, R5, #0
ADD R5, R5, #1  ; init loop counter

OUTP    JSR     COMPARE         ; uses R6 to compare first and last name to search term.
                                ; if they match, continue (R0 = 1). Otherwise, go to NXTNODE.
ADD R0, R0, #-1
BRnp    NXTNODE         ; no match, don't print

LDR R0, R6, #0  ; there was a match. Load first name to R0      

TRAP    x22
LEA R0, SPACE
TRAP    x22
....
```

(The indentation is a little messy from the markdown)

`COMPARE` is located at a different location, in this line:

```
COMPARE ST  R1, ST1     ; R6 --> current node
```

The instruction is never moved to the `COMPARE` label. The simulator just steps by it, on to the next instruction.

It was working as expected before, but I must've changed something, and I have no idea what that is, or why it isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The simulator just steps by it, on to the next instruction.

Just an idea:

Is the code at the `COMPARE` label executed?

Or - to ask differently: Do the registers after the `JSR` instruction have the values you would expect after returning from the subroutine?

If yes the simulator might step in "step over" mode you might know from high-level languages, too.

In this mode a function (high-level language) or subroutine (assembler) is not stepped but it is executed and the debugger stops when the function or subroutine has finished.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as it turns that was my exact problem. Checked again this morning, and realized I was mixing up how to use the debug utility.